# how to get next sequence value using php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR contract_seq

//it will return  next value of sequence 1, 2, 3 etc..i need to insert this sequence number to the database table.Using codeigniter i want to insert sequence number to database table

```
INSERT dbtest.contract (Contract_no) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR pestcontrol.contract_seq) // error Invalid object name 'pestcontrol.contract_seq'.
```

Comment: i have created sequence name contract_seq

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't returned inserted id in model.Try this :

```
public function save_contract($data){ 
         $insert_id = 0;
       if($this->db->insert("contract", $data)){
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return $insert_id;
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function contract_submitted() {

   $data = array(
       'line_of_business_id' => $this->input->post('busi'),
       'Contact_name' => $this->input->post('name')
     );
       $lastID= $this->modal_create_contract->save_contract($data);
       if(!$lastID){
        //Show Error 
        }
       $data['last_id']=$lastID;
       $this->load->view('contract',$data);
    }
```

Comment: how to view this id in view page?inside ajax success

Comment: You need to call this method `contract_submitted()` (URL: base_url()."/controllername/contract_submitted") in ajax and replace `$this->load->view('contract',$data);` to `echo json_encode($data); return;`. By using this you will get `$data` array in ajax success.

Comment: Is your ajax call calling the `contract_submitted` method of the controller?

Comment: when using last inserted id, if two system are trying to insert at a same time means  then i will get wrong id right??

Comment: @becool, no, the `insert_id` function returns the last id inserted on THAT connection only.

Comment: using Next value will return id.u know how to do this?

Comment: No, the server will return a correct id because that doesn't matter how many data were inserted but it will only return id using `$this->db->insert_id();` .